# Removing excess spacing between subsections in Springer template

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I am preparing a paper for a journal in Springer and am using svjour3.cls as my permeable. I see some weird spacing at some parts of my document. Any idea how to fix that? [image]

Comment: presumably you have `\flushbottom` in effect and a large unbreakable thing like a minipage at the top of the next page? You could use `\flushbottom` but changing the style may not be allowed by the author instructions of whatever journal is using this class. So it may be that you have to change the document to allow more text on to this page. As you have given no clue about your source hard to help further.

Comment: sorry meant you could use `\raggedbottom`

Comment: Plese provide a proper MWE that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: @Steradiant Unfortunately my confusion is that it happens occasionally. This is my first time using Springer template and it looks very weird. By adding and removing figures/text/tables, it dynamically changes the spacing like my snapshot posted here. So even if I provide the MWE, I am not sure if you will be able to do it. I'll try to provide one though.

Comment: Re. your MWE, try using \rule{\columnwidth}{...} instead of images.  As for your problem, If you are using [H] for floats, use [htp] instead.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be coming from changing the line spacing to 2.0 for the entire document. But still don't know how I can avoid such weird white spaces between paragraphs if I want to insist on having line stretch of 2.0